# Java - Android can't send data with httpPost

Tags: java, php, android, post, http-post

I got problem with sending data in Android using httpPost. I found some example, and I don't have any error or exception but on the php site $_POST is always empty/null.

So here is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxx.com/test.php");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("v", "123"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Toast.makeText(this, responseText, 5000).show();
        System.out.println(responseText);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

PHP:

`<?php
$t=$_POST['v'];
print $t;
?>`

and it does not prints 123...

addition:

As you can see there is a String *responseText*. 
In that string i can see that there is the "123" what i wanted to print.

Comment: have you added necessary permissions...?

Comment: i do and in responsetext i get back the source of the php site, so seems like i can reach it

Comment: @user1162316 : but u have add only one item in nameValuePairs and created for (2); and try to `$t=$_REQUEST['v']` instead of `$t=$_POST['v']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php $t=$_POST['v']; print $POST['v']; ?>
```

You have typo in the print (you're missing "_").

Change print `$POST['v'];` to print `$_POST['v'];` or simply `print $t;`

Comment: sorry i noticed it while i made this post, just forget to fix it. the reason of my bug is not that. :S

Comment: Well, then I advice you to put some code in your exeception-handling (prints). You don't know if it returns an error like the way you have it now.

Comment: i added the following lines
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

and i edited my post, please read it :)
but there is no exception

Comment: As it has been mentioned remove the "2" from
new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2) since you don't need it.
If you still have no luck try to set the $_POST['v'] on the server side first and check that it prints the result you expect. In other words set $_POST['v'] = "123"; print $_POST['v'];
Is that the ony PHP-code in test.php?

Comment: thank you for helping, i tried what you had said:
1. i've made it nothing changed
2. if i set $_POST['v'] i can print it so it's works
3. that is the only PHP code
4. please take a look at my original post, i've edited it. seems like the server gets some data but it does not stores it. :$

Comment: But you receive 123 according to your post? So, what is the problem then? :S

Comment: At least it works. the problem was, that i tried to fix the code several times and seems like while i tried i made some mess in my code :S:S Sorry, you gave me the right advice but i made some other mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  $inputdata .= $data;
```